# How to reverse digits of an integer mathematically?

Tags: number-theory

Is there a mathematical way to reverse digits of an integer mathematically? for example:
 $18539 \rightarrow 93581$

Comment: You mean like division?

Comment: Like $18539$ becomes $93581$, I would guess. But what should happen if you reverse $10$?

Comment: What does 'reverse an integer' mean?

Comment: You could view every number as a polynomial $p(x)$ with non-negative integer coefficients evaluated at $10$, where the $n^{\text{th}}$ digit (from the right) is the coefficient of $x^n$. Then its reverse is $10^mp(\frac 1{10})$, where $m=\text{deg}\;p$. This would revert $10$ into $1$.

Comment: you mean reverse the digits?

Comment: @copper.hat I interpret your comment as: 1 should be reversed to 1 or should be reversed to 01 to 10. Thus, reversing is not a function unless some other conditions are put.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let $n = \lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor$, then $x$ has $n + 1$ digits; see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/469609/39599).

Let $x = \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^nx_i10^i$ where $x_i \in \{0, 1, \dots, 9\}$. To obtain $x_k$ (i.e. the $(k+1)^{\text{st}}$ digit of $x$), first divide by $10^k$ to obtain

$$x10^{-k} = \sum_{i=0}^nx_i10^{i-k} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_i10^{i-k} + \sum_{i=k}^nx_i10^{i-k}.$$

Note that the first sum on the right hand side is a non-negative number less than $1$ and the second sum is an integer. Therefore

$$\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor = \left\lfloor\sum_{i=0}^nx_i10^{i-k}\right\rfloor = \sum_{i=k}^nx_i10^{i-k}.$$

Now consider the corresponding expression for $k+1$:

\begin{align*}
\lfloor x10^{-(k+1)}\rfloor &= \left\lfloor\sum_{i=0}^nx_i10^{i-(k+1)}\right\rfloor\\ 
&= \sum_{i=k+1}^nx_i10^{i-(k+1)}\\ 
&= 10^{-1} \sum_{i=k+1}^nx_i10^{i-k}\\ 
&= 10^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=k}^nx_i10^{i-k}-x_k\right)\\ 
&= 10^{-1}\left(\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor - x_k\right).
\end{align*}

Rearranging for $x_k$ we find $x_k = \lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor - 10\lfloor x10^{-(k+1)}\rfloor$. Therefore, the number you are after is

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^nx_{n-k}10^k &= \sum_{k=0}^n\left(\lfloor x10^{-(n-k)}\rfloor - 10\lfloor x10^{-(n-k+1)}\rfloor\right)10^k\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-(n-k)}\rfloor10^k - \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-(n-k+1)}\rfloor10^{k+1}
\end{align*}

or if you prefer

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^nx_k10^{n-k} &= \left(\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor - 10\lfloor x10^{-(k+1)}\rfloor\right)10^{n-k}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k} - \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-(k+1)}\rfloor10^{n-k+1}.
\end{align*}

We can simplify this even further. Note that $\lfloor x10^{-n+1}\rfloor = 0$ so the final term in the second sum is zero. Now shift the index in the second sum so that it begins at $k = 1$:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k} - \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-(k+1)}\rfloor10^{n-k+1}\\ 
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k} - \sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k+2}\\
&= \lfloor x10^0\rfloor10^n + \sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k} - 100\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k}\\
&= x10^n - 99\sum_{k=1}^n\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{n-k}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, given a positive integer $x$, the integer which has the same digits in the reverse order is $$x10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor} - 99\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor}\lfloor x10^{-k}\rfloor10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor-k}.$$

---

Here's an example calculation. Let $x = 123$, then $\lfloor \log_{10}x\rfloor = 2$. As $\lfloor x10^{-1}\rfloor = \lfloor 12.3\rfloor = 12$ and $\lfloor x10^{-2}\rfloor = \lfloor 1.23\rfloor = 1$, we have

$$123\times 10^2 - 99\left(12\times 10 + 1\times 1\right) = 123\times 100 - 99\times 121 = 12300 - 11979 = 321$$

as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a recursive formula:

$$R(N)=U(N)10^{[log(N)]}+R([N/10])$$

where

$$U(N)=N-10[N/10]$$

is the "unit" digit of $N$ (i.e., the digit in the "ones" column), and $R(0)$ is understood to equal $0$.  The logarithm is base $10$, and the square brackets indicate the greatest-integer (floor) function.

Note:  reversing digits is *not* an involution when $U(N)=0$.  E.g., $R(100)=1$, but R($1)\neq100$.

**Added later**:  It occurs to me that the recursive formula adapts nicely to digit reversal in any base:

$$R_b(N) = U_b(N)b^{[log_b(N)]}+R_b([N/b])$$

where

$$U_b(N)=N-b[N/b]$$

Answer (score -1):

```
let number be 123. 
perform 123%10 = 3 = a
perform 123/10 =12
if not 0,then multiply a with 10, so a = 30 
perform 12%10 = b 
perform 12/10 = 1
if not 0, then multiply b with 10 & a with 10,so a = 300 & b = 20
perform 1%10 = c 
perform 1/10 = 0
if not 0, continue....however, as this is 0, you stop the process.
just add a+b+c. = 300+20+1 = 321
```

& in terms of pure mathematics:

sum of [{floor of n/10^(N-1-k)}*{10^k] for k= 0 to N-1. where n is integer, & N is no of digits.

Comment: % stands for modulo operation, & result of divide by 10 is an integer,not a fraction.

Comment: I can't be certain (given the scant amount of information the OP gave), but I think the asker was looking for a single closed form equation rather than an algorithm.

Comment: sum of [{floor of n/10^(N-1-k)}*{10^k] for k= 0 to N-1.

where n is integer, & N is no of digits.

Comment: & why the vote down guys ? Atleast give the reasons !!

Comment: This is a Math question not programming!

Comment: I gave my reason above, but in addition to that, your symbols and math aren't correct. For example, $12/10$ does not equal $1$, and in mathematics, $\%$ does not work the way that you're using it.

Comment: @Ataraxia. In computer-speak, it's often the case that for positive integers $n, m$ the expression $\mathtt{n/m}$ denotes what mathematicians would call $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$.

Comment: I know, but this is mathematics, not programming.

Comment: @Ataraxia. Indeed.

Comment: I think its fine to use any symbol as long as you are clear on what it means. So its ok to use $\%$ the way Sumedh did but may be he should have stated how he was using it. I think most people who know math has had exposure to at least a bit of computer science so its not such a big deal in my opinion.

Comment: @Ataraxia, I already told about % & divide by 10 results into an integer, in my first comment,before anyone of you pointed that out. However,I do admit I was wrong in the way I wrote the answer,but I do hope that instead of voting down an answer, you'll allow the poster to edit it. Vote down is done when the answer is wrong, which wasnt the case here.