# Adding the reverse of digits

Tags: number-theory

You start with an integer $n$. Repeat the following process $i$ times:

$n=$ $n+\text{the reverse of n} $

By 'reverse' I mean the digits of the number are flipped, ie $123 \rightarrow 321$.

Is there a general formula for the eventual result in terms of $n$ and $i$? I've tried expressing it more mathematically to try to get an answer, but 'reversing digits' doesn't seem to be something expressable as a formula.

Comment: Reversing digits can be written explicity, see [here for example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480068/how-to-reverse-digits-of-an-integer-mathematically?rq=1), but I don't expect there to be a nice clean result except for special cases for your general question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple recursive algorithm:

```
// Precondition: n >= 0
// Postcondition: n with its digits reversed
int reverse(int n)
{
    if (n < 10) {
        return n;
    } else {
        int last_digit = n % 10;
        int ten_power  = pow(10, (int)log10(n));
        return last_digit * ten_power + reverse(n/10);
    }  
}
```

So, `reverse(123456)` returns $654321$.

If $n \geq 0$, the formula may be written as
$$\mathrm{rev}(n) = \begin{cases}
n,&\text{if }n < 10\\
k\cdot 10^{\lceil\log_{10}(n)\rceil} + \textrm{rev}(\lfloor n/10\rfloor),&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
where $k$ is the last digit of $n$. That is, $k$ is the remainder of $n/10$, or equivalently,  $$k = n - 10 \lfloor \frac{n}{10} \rfloor$$

Comment: So how can I apply this to solve my question mathematically?

Comment: This is just a hint to your problem with the "reversing digits" part. I think you wouldn't go much further with this recursive formula, but it is an idea.